# BootstrapValidator ignoring Enter keypress on complete form

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrapvalidator

We're using bootstrapValidator to validate all our forms, but on our login form if the user presses <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd> and everything is valid, nothing happens.

Here's the html we're using:

```
<form id="signin" name="signin" class="validate-live" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label sr-only" for="email">Email</label>  
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" 
                class="form-control"
                data-bv-notempty="true"
                data-bv-notempty-message="Please enter your email"
            >
        </div>

        <!-- Password -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label sr-only" for="password">Password</label>  
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"
                class="form-control"
                data-bv-notempty="true"
                data-bv-notempty-message="Please enter your password"
            >
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="submit_button" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-next">Sign in</button>
        <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-link-secondary btn-forgot" >Forgot password?</a>            
      </fieldset> 
    </form>
```

and the bootstrapValidator code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.validate-live').bootstrapValidator({
        live: 'enabled',
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        submitButtons: '#submit_button',
        trigger: null
    }).on('error.field.bv', function(e, data) {
        data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
    }).on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
        data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
        if (data.bv.getInvalidFields().length>0) {
            data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
        }
    });
});
```

I've added some console.logs to the event handlers, and they showed that the validator activates on the keypresses, and if the form's invalid then the prompts get displayed, but if the form's fine nothing happens until the user actually clicks on the `#submit_button` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing any reason to assign `submitButtons: '#submit_button'`

Just remove `submitButtons: '#submit_button',` will fix the issue.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.validate-live').bootstrapValidator({
    live: 'enabled',
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    //submitButtons: '#submit_button',
    trigger: null
  }).on('error.field.bv', function(e, data) {
    data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
  }).on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
    data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
    if (data.bv.getInvalidFields().length > 0) {
      data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(true);
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="signin" name="signin" class="validate-live" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="Please enter your email">
    </div>

    <!-- Password -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" data-bv-notempty="true" data-bv-notempty-message="Please enter your password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="submit_button" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-next">Sign in</button>
    <a href="reset-password.php" class="btn btn-link-secondary btn-forgot">Forgot password?</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnzj9foy/)

Comment: What about if my form had multiple buttons? The JS code is held in an include file and used on multiple pages, with a lot of different forms

Comment: change `type` of all other buttons from `submit` to `button`

Comment: see if this helps https://jsfiddle.net/tnzj9foy/1/, there is other way to bind the form submit button with bootstrapValidator without effecting other multiple buttons or changing their type